# preg replace twitter status and http or https PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter, preg-replace, status

I'll start with what I have:

```
// embed tweet
$embed_tweet =  '
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-cards="hidden" data-lang="en">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/\\4"></a>
  </blockquote>
';

$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('#(<a href="http://twitter.com)?/(status/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)">(http://twitter.com)?/(status/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)<\/a>#i', $embed_tweet, $this->post['message']);

// embed vine
$embed_player =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/\\4/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('#(<a href="http://vine.co)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)">(http://vine.co)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)<\/a>#i', $embed_player, $this->post['message']);
```

I am trying to make it so when a user posts a link to a Twitter status or a Vine post it auto embeds the post.

The Vine code was given to me and I managed to update parts of it and get it working only if its `http` or I added the `s` I can only make it one way or the other, I tried working from it to get the Twitter one to function.

But I have no idea hot to figure out the proper `preg_replace` for the Twitter embed.

A Twitter status link is as follows:

```
https://twitter.com/DrCustUmz/status/726561400617840641
```

So if a user posts that link like that and the post is submitted, it turns into:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/DrCustUmz/status/726561400617840641" taget="_blank">https://twitter.com/DrCustUmz/status/726561400617840641</a>
```

So how can I achieve this, and how do I go about getting what I need for a `preg_replace`?

Also... What does that `\\4` do exactly in the line

```
$embed_player =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/\\4/embed/simple"...
```

Comment: I figured out the http or s part using `$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('#(<a href="https?://vine.co)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)">(https?://vine.co)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|v\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)<\/a>#i', $embed_player, $this->post['message']);` Seems to do the trick, I still don't know if that's proper though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went on the learning more journey and this is what I came up with.

```
// embed tweet
$drc_embed_tweet =  '
  <blockquote align="center" class="twitter-tweet" data-cards="hidden" data-lang="en">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/\2/status/\3"></a>
  </blockquote>
';
$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://twitter.com)/(.*)/status/(.*)">(https?://twitter.com)/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_tweet, $this->post['message']);

// embed vine

$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe align="center" src="https://vine.co/v/\2" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $this->post['message']);
```

As for the numbers `\4` From my understanding that is the portion of the reg. ex. being replace since the second reg. ex. `\2` is the same thing either number can be used.